# Let $X$ be a point on $AB$ such that $AX=2(BX)$.Find a vector representation for $\vec X $ in terms of $\vec A$ and $\vec B$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $X$ be a point on $AB$ such that $AX=2(BX)$.Find a vector
>   representation for $\vec X$ in terms of $ \vec A $ and $\vec B$.

**My work**

Define the origin of vectors $\vec A $ and $\vec B$ to be point $O$,so that $\vec A =\vec {OA}$ and $\vec B=\vec {OB}$.

Then ,by definition, we have
$\vec {BA} =\vec A - \vec B  $ (Head of vector at $A$ and tail at $B$)

Now,

$AX=2BX$ $\implies$ $BA-BX=2BX$ $\implies \cfrac{\vec A -\vec B}{3}=BX=\vec{BX}$

Then we have that $$\vec {OX} =\vec B + \vec {BX} =\vec B +\cfrac{\vec A -\vec B}{3}=\cfrac{2\vec B +\vec A}{3}$$

**Question**

This exercise from my book is marked as difficult so I am asking your expertise to be sure that I have got it right.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $AX=2(BX)$, there should be two situations.

First,
$$\overrightarrow{AX}=2\overrightarrow{BX}$$
Then 
$$\vec {OX}-\vec{OA}=2(\vec{OX}-\vec{OB})$$
$$\vec{OX}=2\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$$
Or
$$\vec{AX}=2\vec{XB}$$
Then
$$\vec {OX}-\vec{OA}=2(\vec{OB}-\vec{OX})$$
$$\vec{OX}=\frac{2\vec{OB}+\vec{OA}}3$$

Comment: Last equation is wrong $\vec {OX}=\cfrac{2 \vec{OB}}{3} +\cfrac{\vec{OA}}{3} $

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: No problem.Thanks for your answer .